# How to fix "Couldn’t sign you in This browser or app may not be secure." with selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium

Hi in my script I'm trying to implement a sign-in to Gmail but I've done lots of research to try and get around this but I keep getting the same display, I've seen lots saying go to stack overflow and sign in to gmail through there but that doesn't work anymore. My script is mainly based around Python and its modules only, I've experimented with adding and removing lots of different chrome options and nothing has worked so far.
What I've tried so far:

- Using proxies
- Using a user agent
- Using options such as ['chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu"),
  'chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']),
  'chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]),
  'chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security'),
  'chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content'),]

If anyone knows a fix please let me know. Thanks :)

My current code looks like this:

```
import zipfile
from selenium import webdriver


def driverConfig(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    proxy = ""
    colon1 = proxy.find(":") + 1
    colon2 = proxy.find(":", colon1) + 1
    colon2ActualEnding = proxy.find(":", colon1)
    colon3 = proxy.find(":", colon2) + 1  # rp_user_4674
    colonEnding = proxy.find(":", colon3)
    host = proxy[:colon1-1]
    port = proxy[colon1:colon2ActualEnding]
    user = proxy[colon2:colon3-1]
    password = proxy[colon3:]
    background_js = """
        var config = {
                mode: "fixed_servers",
                rules: {
                singleProxy: {
                    scheme: "http",
                    host: "%s",
                    port: parseInt(%s)
                },
                bypassList: ["localhost"]
                }
            };

        chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

        function callbackFn(details) {
            return {
                authCredentials: {
                    username: "%s",
                    password: "%s"
                }
            };
        }

        chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
                    callbackFn,
                    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
                    ['blocking']
        );
        """ % (host, port, user, password)
    manifest_json = """
                {
                    "version": "1.0.0",
                    "manifest_version": 2,
                    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
                    "permissions": [
                        "proxy",
                        "tabs",
                        "unlimitedStorage",
                        "storage",
                        "<all_urls>",
                        "webRequest",
                        "webRequestBlocking"
                    ],
                    "background": {
                        "scripts": ["background.js"]
                    },
                    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
                }
                """
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
                zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
                zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
            chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
            chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
                'excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
                "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option(
                'useAutomationExtension', False)
            chrome_options.add_argument(
                '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
            chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
            chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
            chrome_options.add_argument(
                '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path='C:\webdrivers1\chromedriver.exe',
        options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

Comment: Share the code you have created so far.

Comment: The way we can help you is for us to be able to run your code so that we can see what's wrong with it. Right now something is missing in your code because you define a function but never call it. We cannot presume how you are going to call it because the error could be there. Could you provide a [example] in the description of your question?